# Change dashboard language in Honda Fit 2012

Tags: honda

I need to change the dashboard language of my car, because it's always in Japanese or Chinese and I can't understand it.

Please check these pictures I took of the screen.

I think if anyone can read Japanese or Chinese it will help to understand. (I am not sure if this is in Chinese or Japanese).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not that it's terrible helpful, but it's Japanese. Chinese idiograms are more "boxy".

Comment: FYI: no, I can't actually read japanese, I just know what it looks like. talk about a useless skill :(

Comment: What does the owner's manual say about changing the language?

Comment: AOA, I have a similar problem, have you found a solution yet. Would you be willing to put in the link, it you have found the solution from another site. That would be great. Thanks

Comment: I'm my fit car also this problem how I reset or change a laguage ...

Comment: @Adilurrehman please check the below answer for help. you cannot change the language. by default its Japanase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one: Customize Settings

Second: Default Setting

Third: Meter Settings

Fourth: Smart Key Settings

Fifth: Lighting Settings

Sixth: Door Settings

Seventh: "Return" (like back to your main menu I'm guessing)